# Installing ZeroMQ bindings for Node.js on CentOS fails

Tags: node.js, centos, npm, zeromq, node-gyp

So I'm trying to install ZeroMQ with bindings for Node.js on my CentOS VPS, but it just fails and I have no clue whatsoever how to fix it.

I'm running CentOS 6.5.

I've installed Node.js 0.10.26 using:

```
sudo yum install nodejs npm
```

I've installed ZeroMQ 2.2.0 using:

```
sudo yum install zeromq
```

And finally tried to install the ZeroMQ bindings using package.json with "zmq" version "2.7.x" as a dependency and then running:

```
npm install
```

The process fails at the command:

```
node-gyp rebuild


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 18, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'script_main'
```

I'm not sure where to look at for the solution. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Python do you have installed (`python -V`) and what version of npm (`npm -v`)?

Comment: Python 2.6.8 and npm 1.3.21

Comment: npm v1.4.3 is what is bundled with node v0.10.26, it's unfortunate that CentOS hasn't kept the two in sync. You could try updating npm manually with `curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` and see if that helps any (`npm -v` should then give you 1.4.7).

Comment: Just for the record CentOS 6 has neither nodejs nor npm packages. They are both in EPEL.